# sound notification when message received from mixpanel

Tags: android, notifications, push, mixpanel

I have integrated mixpanel in my android app code, and I am getting push notifications but I want to hear the default notification sound when the message arrives. 
So I added the following:

```
    public class notificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent MainActivity) {
         NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
Uri notification =  RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mBuilder.setSound(notification);
Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context.getApplicationContext(),    notification);
    r.play();  }
}
```

Any reason why this doesn't make sound to the mixpanel notification?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You must add this line of code in your notification builder

```
mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
```